# Grafana (The repository 'https://packages.grana.com/oss/deb stable release' does not have a Release file

Tags: server, 22.04

When I use to update my ubuntu server there's an error I encountered.
I tried to search it online, but it does not work.

ERROR: The repository 'https://packages.grana.com/oss/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CrM7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (or the appropriate file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. The most likely file for this would be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grafana.list`.

You have written `https://packages.grana.com/oss/deb`, where it should instead be `https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb`.

Insert the missing `fa` in the correct file, and it will work.